# Debugging on Eclipse using Remote Java Application

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

I have a hellowworld JSP running properly on the browser. I have added a toggle point on Eclipse hellowworld code. I started the tomcat like `catalina jpda start` in debug mode and then run the "Debug" from the Eclipse as shown in the windows below :

[image]

After clicking the debug button, I can see the following on the debug console :

[image]

However, I am wondering why my eclipse is not displaying a window something like the following ( I just took the following screenshot from the [website](https://cdn.tutsplus.com/mobile/authors/legacy/Shane%20Conder%20and%20Lauren%20Darcey/2012/09/25/Android-App-Debugging_Eclipse-debug-perspective.png) for explaining purpose) for my hellowworld application :

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The screenshot you attached shows your Eclipse in [Debug view](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fviews%2Fdebug%2Fref-debug_view.htm). Follow the instructions mentioned in the [link](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftasks-debug-launch.htm) here to launch your Java program on Eclipse in Debug view.

Comment: Could you explain in more detail ?

Comment: Thanks. That worked. I am trying to test my another folders that I loaded in eclipse work space, added a breakpoint and tsting via an api and the eclipse isn't noticing anything. However, it works for hellowworld.

Answer (score 0):

Are you in Debug Perspective? 
**Window > Open Perspective > Debug.**

Refresh your breakpoints, remove all breakpoints then toggle it again.

Try to run your eclipse as an administrator.